# Square UIImageView and UITextField in UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiimageview, uitextfield, constraints

I'm trying to create a cell that contains a square UIImageView and a UITextField. If the text fits the width of the screen, then everything works fine. But as soon as I change the text to a longer one, the presentation breaks down. There are no messages in the console about the correctness of the constraints.

When the text in the UITextField fits on the screen or UITextField contains only placeholder everything works fine.

[image: screenshot when all works fine]

But if the text is long enough, the presentation breaks down.

[image]

The code with which I create the view:

```
extension TextFieldWithImageTVCell {

    private func initView() {
        selectionStyle = .none
        initImgView()
        initTextField()
        contentView.addSubview(imgView)
        contentView.addSubview(textField)

        // debug code
        imgView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    }

    private func initImgView() {
        imgView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }

    private func initTextField() {
        textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect.zero)
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }

}
```

The code with which I create constraints:

```
extension TextFieldWithImageTVCell {

    private func initConstraints() {
        initConstraintsImgView()
        initConstraintsTextField()
    }

    private func initConstraintsImgView() {
        imgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        let margins = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        imgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        imgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.topAnchor).isActive = true
        imgView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    private func initConstraintsTextField() {
        textField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.trailingAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        let margins = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        textField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.topAnchor).isActive = true
        textField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        textField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }

}
```

The part of code with which I configure cell:

```
cell.textContent = subject
cell.placeholder = "Предмет"
cell.isEditingEnabled = true

guard let textField = cell.textField else {
    assertionFailure("error in ItemSubject::configureCellForRow")
    return
}

textField.delegate = self
textField.clearButtonMode = .always
textField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
textField.minimumFontSize = 10
```

Cell properties:

```
extension TextFieldWithImageTVCell {

    var placeholder: String? {
        set { textField.placeholder = newValue }
        get { return textField.placeholder }
    }

    var textContent: String? {
        set { textField.text = newValue }
        get { return textField.text }
    }

    var isEditingEnabled: Bool {
        set { textField.isUserInteractionEnabled = newValue }
        get { return textField.isUserInteractionEnabled }
    }

}
```

What constraints do I need to add to achieve the desired result?
Why are my constraints not enough?

Comment: What do you mean breaks down, I don't understand the problem?

Comment: @user3069232 The first screenshot shows two cells. Both are displayed correctly. The second screenshot also shows two cells, but the first one is displayed incorrectly. From it all views disappear.

Comment: And what causes the first view to disappear? A string within it that is too large to fit in the field?

Comment: @user3069232, `cell.textContent = "short text"` works good, but `cell.textContent = "very very very very very very very very very very very long text"` not good

Comment: Just a suggestion, have you tried to apply the constraints thru Xcode and not via code? You could also try removing them all together and see what it does?